# Analog of PHP .htaccess for JSP/Glassfish

Tags: java, jsp, glassfish

How is it possible to restrict files(PDF) access in JSP/Glassfish so they can be opened only from a source code not with a straight url. For PHP projects I used .htaccess.

Answer (score 2):

Anything under the webapp's `WEB-INF` directory cannot be accessed via direct URL, but application code can access it. This is a good place to put internal resources, config, JSPs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Wow,

.htaccess is an Apache HTTPD feature. As far as I know there isn't anything comparable in GlassFish. What you could do is: Write a Servlet or Servlet Filter which takes care of this and/or map the *.pdf extension in web.xml to it..

Thanks,
M