# How to make .htaccess file in java?

Tags: java, hibernate, .htaccess

I was checking the performance of my site on gtmatrix and found that Leverage browser caching  is not well.They are showing that expiration date not specified to my css,js and images.For that i need to specify expiration date of them in .htaccess file.I read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19146-01/821-0793/gdeun/index.html) but didn't understand how to make .htaccess file in java.My project is based on hibernate and i am using glassfish server.Could anybody tell me how to create .htaccess file in java.

Comment: Read up how to create files with Java, then creating a file named ".htaccess" will be only a specific case for your file creation example.

Comment: @Smutje I know how to create files with java but i don't know which syntax to use in `.htaccess` files.

Comment: Perhaps you could refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067719/controlling-cache-expirations?rq=1

Comment: @Smutje Just 1 question where should i place this file.I think where all my JSP pages are or somewhere else.

Comment: @Smutje also when i am creating a `.htaccess` file it says you must specify file name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess not working apache-tomcat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10528552/htaccess-not-working-apache-tomcat)

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov I am using glassfish not apache tomcat

Comment: There is no difference in your case. That answer answers your question too

Comment: Here is exact duplicate if you wish http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031079/analog-of-php-htaccess-for-jsp-glassfish